# How to integrate client_secret json file and to get google credentials in android for google classroom api

Tags: android, google-classroom

I want to integrate oauth id in classroom apis,i have download client_secret.json from google api console for create android application ,
Previously i am passing the credentials based on email, now i want to change as oauth id without asking emails.

this is my code: but this code i take from google classroom apis using java,but its not working in android.Please someone help me.

```
InputStream in =
                Sample1.class.getResourceAsStream("/client_secret.json");
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets =
                null;
        try {
            clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow =
                null;

        flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, Arrays.asList(SCOPES))
                .setAccessType("offline")
                .build();

        try {
            credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(
                    flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

when i run this code i got the url  like this:
** https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?access_type=offline&client_id=542678605378-g1h3b23dm59f8eeulbndss52dud1sr6e.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http://localhost:38503/Callback&response_type=code&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.courses.readonly
**

But actually original url for accessing google classroom 
apis:***https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.courses.readonly***

Comment: Try the [Android Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/classroom/quickstart/android), I think the code for authentication already has the feature that you want to achieve. Hope this helps.

Comment: in android quickstart they are using email authentication they didn't use 0auth client id and all.